# the minimal deterministic finite automaton recognizing $\{1^n 0^n /n\leq N\}$

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata

Given a language $L$ how can I determine the number of states of the minimal automate which recognizes $L$. I want some examples and to understand the methods that we can use to find a lower bound for the number of states ,for example:

> Let $Σ=\{0,1\}$ and $L=\{1^n0^n /n\leq N\}$
>
> What is the minimal number of states of deterministic finite automaton which recognizes $L$?

I use the following definition of an automate:

A deterministic finite automaton is represented formally by a $5$-tuple $(Q,Σ,δ,q_0,F)$, where:

- $Q$ is a finite set of states.
- $Σ$ is a finite set of symbols, called the alphabet of the automaton.
- $δ$ is the transition function, that is, $δ: Q × Σ → Q$.
- $q_0$ is the start state, that is, the state of the automaton before any input has been processed, where $q_0∈ Q$.
- $F$ is a set of states of $Q$ (i.e. $F⊆Q$) called accept states.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If I am correct this language is a classic example of non regular language so it cannot be recognized with finite automaton.

Comment: I'm just looking for an example so that's why i come up with this one and it turns out that it's not regular, so I changed it. The most important thing for me is to understand which methods can we use to determine the number of minimal states.

Comment: I think this link should help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem

Answer (score 2):

There are standard algorithms for *minimizing* a DFA, producing another DFA that recognizes the the same language as the input DFA and has the smallest number of states among all DFAs that recognize this language. Any halfway adequate text in automata theory ought to explain them in excruciating detail.

Thus, if you have a regular language and want to know a strict lower bound for a the size of a DFA that recognizes it:

1. Construct *some* DFA for the language, usually (depending on which kind of description of the language you have already) by applying standard algorithms.
2. Minimize the DFA.
3. Count the number of states in the minimal DFA.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! this was interesting ,but I have changed the language $L$ which is now finite so it's regular?

Comment: @Elaqqad: Yes, finite languages are always regular. (Try constructing the minimal DFA for several small $N$. Notice a pattern?)